# Div not showing when radio button checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button that will show a div with an input text when it is checked 'NO'. But it is not showing the div, however when I play around the radio button then the div will show. Where am I missing?

```js
function CheckboxCheck(checkbox) {
  var firstCheckbox = document.getElementById('check1');
  var secondCheckbox = document.getElementById('check2');
  var rmk = document.getElementById("rmk");
  if (firstCheckbox.checked == true) {
    rmk.style.display = "none";
  } else if (secondCheckbox.checked == true) {
    rmk.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("rmk").required = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Have you registered the course?</label>
  <table border=0>
    <tr>
      <td>YES&emsp;</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="register" value="Y" id="check1" onclick="CheckboxCheck('first')">&emsp;&emsp;</td>
      <td>NO&emsp;</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="register" value="N" checked id="check2" onclick="CheckboxCheck('second')"></td>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="rmk" style="display:none">
  <label>Reasons</label>
  <input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: You're only calling your CheckboxCheck function when the radio buttons are clicked, not also when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few structure and accessibility proposals going on in this suggestion but I think strictly speaking, the easiest solve for you is to invoke the function on page load. Give this example a look:

```js
function CheckboxCheck(checkbox) {
  var firstCheckbox = document.getElementById('check1');
  var secondCheckbox = document.getElementById('check2');

  var rmk = document.getElementById("rmk");
  var rmkdiv = document.getElementById("rmk-div");

  if (firstCheckbox.checked == true) {
    rmkdiv.style.display = "none";
  } else if (secondCheckbox.checked == true) {
    rmkdiv.style.display = "block";
    rmk.required = true;
  }
}

CheckboxCheck()
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Have you registered the course?</p>
  <label>
    YES<input
      type="radio"
      name="register"
      value="Y"
      id="check1"
      onclick="CheckboxCheck()"
  /></label>
  <label>NO
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="register"
      value="N"
      checked
      id="check2"
      onclick="CheckboxCheck()"
    />
  </label>
  <div id="rmk-div" style="display: none">
    <label>Reasons</label>
    <input id="rmk" type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, this actually work on this post but when I paste your code the div is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your input field will only be visible when the function `CheckboxCheck` is executed. Since "NO" is checked from the beginning, the function will not be executed because it is only called when a change takes place.

Comment: is it because of the onclick function? is there any other example I can use?